# Get CheckBox value in a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a Model with OtherCountries as a `List<string>`. Before each country I need to put a checkbox:

```
@foreach (string country in Model.OtherCountries)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
                @Translations.Text
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxCountry" id="checkboxCountry" value="true"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
              <textarea name="@(Html.NameFor(m => m.OtherCountries))" class="form-control textarea-resize" rows="5">@country</textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

With the submit button I can send the Model to a Controller but my problem is that I don't know which checkbox belongs to which country? Every country has a checkbox in front of it but If I want for example to delete a country from the list I have to do that based on the checkbox.

Comment: Create a model for your view with the information you need will make this easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to create a View Model for this case, in that View Model you can add fields with the names of the countries like:

```
public [datatype] USA {get; set;}
```

The name of the View Model can be: `public class CountriesViewModel`

Now, when you populate your View, you can add those names to the check-boxes so when you send the information back to the controller you can do this in your view:

```
@foreach (string country in Model.OtherCountries)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
            @Translations.Text
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="@country" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
          <textarea name="@(Html.NameFor(m => m.OtherCountries))" class="form-control textarea-resize" rows="5">@country</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Then you can expect in your controller this:

```
public ActionResult CountriesController(CountriesViewModel contries)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model to wrap country name and a boolean selected and replace the list of string OtherCountries by a list of this new model. From then just link the value of the checkbox with the selected property of every country and the name with the label so in the controller once you click submit you will have the information you want.